# Is it possible to skew actor in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Is it possible to skew/shear actor (image) in `libgdx`?

I have found that skew is possible for sprites, as [discussed here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=30810.0)

What about an actor?

Comment: Sure it is possible. Take a look at AssetManager and Texture Atlas. You just have one image which holds alot of small images and you just refare to the one image (Or parts of it). Common system in games. But a Actor at least has no image! You need to extend that actor. Since Sprite is a actor extended by an image it is possible there. But sure you can write your own Actor which holds an image and draw it inside of the render. Pass the image from a Texture Atlas and you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
class SkewActor extends Actor {
    private TextureRegion tex;
    private Affine2 affine = new Affine2();

    public SkewActor(TextureRegion textureRegion) {
        this.tex = textureRegion;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        Color color = getColor();
        batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);

        affine.setToTranslation(getX(), getY());
        affine.shear(0.5f, 0);  // <- modify skew here
        batch.draw(tex,getWidth(), getHeight(), affine);

    }
}
```