# libgdx - Transform/Shear ImageButton

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, affinetransform

I am currently developing an Android game using libgdx, and want to achieve an effect similar to the "friends leaderboard" from the below screenshot:

[image]

<sup>[[Image source](https://www.androidheadlines.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/AH-Run-Sackboy-Run-2.jpg) / Run Sackboy! Run, © Media Molecule & Sony Computer Entertainment]</sup>

Where libgdx should shear an image and draw sheared text and add an ImageButton accordingly.

When searching across the web for a place to start, I found a [handy PDF](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3152/2015sp/lectures/15-SpriteGraphics.pdf) that explained that transformations in libgdx can be modeled using `Matrix4`. So, I did just that and wrote something along the lines of:

```
// Inside a Screen class

private Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4().set(new Affine2().shear(0.5f, 0));

public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.setTransformationMatrix(matrix);

    batch.begin();
    // Draw texture and bitmapfont
    batch.end();
}
```

In doing so, the `SpriteBatch` correctly transformed into the corresponding shear value. However, I had trouble applying this shear transformation to a clickable `ImageButton`.

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988823/is-it-possible-to-skew-actor-in-libgdx) post, which suggests to override the draw method and apply an `Affine2` in an extended `Actor` class. Doing such will result in the correct transformation being rendered, however, it is not applicable because I am trying to extend an `ImageButton` and not a simple `Actor`, and the ability to get the user's input on the Button is lost.

So my question is: Is there a way to create a function similar to `Actor#setRotation` which allows an `ImageButton` to be sheared according to an `Affine2` (or `Matrix4`), while maintaining the ability to click on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web for hours, I just don't think this is possible. Instead of doing this I alternatively just sheared the `Spritebatch` and left the `ImageButton` alone, using [this page](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11176&p=52890) as a guide.